# Is there any context-free language that is inherently ambiguous as an indexed language

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, grammars, ambiguity

Indexed languages are defined as being produced by indexed grammar.

Is there any context-free language that is inherently ambiguous as an indexed language? That is, is there a context-free language without any indexed grammar which may produce every word or sentence of the language in a unique way? Or in other word, may all context-free language  be produced by indexed grammar in a unique way?

Answer (score 4):

*I just wrote this in [an answer to the OP's other question on this topic](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/52184/2367), but for reasons of self-containedness, let me just reproduce the relevant part again:*

This is an open question, which is explicitly stated in the paper

*Adams, Jared; Freden, Eric; Mishna, Marni*, [**From indexed grammars to generating functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/ita/2013041), RAIRO, Theor. Inform. Appl. 47, No. 4, 325-350 (2013). [ZBL1286.68331](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1286.68331).

They also provide some examples which they conjecture to be inherently ambiguous indexed languages:

> Consider Crestin’s language of palindrome pairs defined by
> $L_{Crestin} =  \{vw : v, w \in (a|b)^* , v = v^R w = w^R\}$. It is a
> “worst case” example of an inherently ambiguous context-free language
> (see [8] and its references). We conjecture that $L_{Crestin}$ remains
> inherently ambiguous as an indexed language.